# Force newline in sequence diagram comment

Tags: line-breaking

I am using msc package to generate message sequence charts, here is [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/msc/manual.pdf). I want to make a comment in 2 lines, because it does not fit in one line on my page. I tried `\newline` but it didn't work. Comments I am talking about:

```
\msccomment[position]{text}{instname}
```

How can I force comment on 2 lines?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\title{aaa}
\author{aaa }

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\subsection{whatever}
\begin{center}
\begin{msc}{diagram}
\setlength{\instdist}{9cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{2\envinstdist}
\declinst{dd}{}{DD}
\declinst{ff}{}{FF}
\nextlevel[2]
\mess{something}{dd}{ff}
\msccomment[r]{my very long comment is here}{ff}
\end{msc}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output is like this:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jens_bo thank you, done. I am not sure which packages are needed to compile this, so I'll just leave all of them. I compile it with Xelatex.

Comment: If you are using xelatex you should definitely not be using inputenc, and probably not fontenc either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but thing is, I had all these packages before and now I need to make sequence diagram, and this msc package requires Xelatex.. I cannot produce pdf with pdflatex.

Comment: well remove `inputenc` (with 2014 latex it does nothing with xetex, with older ones it would mess your document up completely) you can just about get away with using classic tex fonts and T1 encoding if you only have ascii input not acented latters. as far as I can see the only dependency is pstrics so it doesn't need xetex you could use latex/dvips or even probably pdflatex with pdf-auto-pst or whatever it's called to run pstricks in pdflatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle alright. Apparently I need to run `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` but I am not sure where do I put this in my vimrc. Because I use vim latex.

Comment: @user1880405 don't ask me about vim (I know `esc :q` and that's enough for me:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\title{aaa}
\author{aaa }

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\subsection{whatever}
\begin{center}
\begin{msc}{diagram}
\setlength{\instdist}{9cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{2\envinstdist}
\declinst{dd}{}{DD}
\declinst{ff}{}{FF}
\nextlevel[2]
\mess{something}{dd}{ff}

\msccomment[r]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
my very\\long\\ comment\\ is here\end{tabular}}{ff}
\end{msc}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```