# Need multiple lines in \mscomment

Tags: line-breaking, msc

I am using the [MSC package](http://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/) for sequence diagrams. I need to make a multiple-lines right-side comment. I tried to add `\\`  but this result in error. This is the minimal script and you need the package file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{msc} %for the diagrams


\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!tp] 
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\setmsckeyword{} %removes msc keyword from the title
\drawframe{no} %no frame

\begin{msc}[normal values, /msc/level height=0.6cm, /msc/label distance=0.5ex , /msc/first level height=0.6cm, /msc/last level height=0.6cm, /msc/top head dist=0, /msc/bottom foot dist=0]{}
\setlength{\instwidth}{2.5\mscunit} 
\setlength{\instdist}{4\mscunit} %message width

\declinst{A}{}{A}
\declinst{B}{}{B}
\declinst{C}{}{C}

\mess {Message 1)}{A}{B}
\mess {Message1}{B}{C}
\nextlevel

\mess {Message2}{B}{C}
\nextlevel
\msccomment[msccomment distance=1cm, side=right]{Very long comment here I need multiple lines}{C}

\end{msc}
} %end scalebox
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I saw a similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215537/force-newline-in-sequence-diagram-comment) but the solution posted here does not work at all. It result in error. Can you please try my example and help my resolve the problem.

**EDIT:**
After removing the `msc.sty` file from the directory where the `.tex` file is located, I got this error:

```
main.tex(11): Error: Undefined control sequence.
main.tex(11): Error: Missing number, treated as zero.
main.tex(11): Error: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
: ''(29): Error: Missing number, treated as zero.
: ''(29): Error: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
: ''(29): Error: Package calc Error: `m' invalid at this point.
: ''(31): Error: Package msc Error: illegal title placement specifier: normal values, /msc/level height=0.6cm, /msc/label distance=0.5ex , /msc/first level height=0.6cm, /msc/last level height=0.6cm, /msc/top head dist=0, /msc/bottom foot dist=0.
: ''(31): Error: Undefined control sequence.
: ''(31): Error: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
: ''(31): Error: Missing } inserted.
main.tex(31): Error: LaTeX Error: \begin{lrbox} on input line 15 ended by \end{msc}.
main.tex(32): Error: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
main.tex(33): Error: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
main.tex(33): Error: Missing } inserted.
main.tex(34): Error: LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 9 ended by \end{document}.
main.tex(34): Error: You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
main.tex(34): Error: LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 9 ended by \end{document}.
main.tex(34): Error: Missing } inserted.
```

**EDIT 2:** 
Package link updated to the new version.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? For instance, `\resizebox` requires an additional package such as `graphicx`. But even if this is fixed, the code does not run through.

Comment: You need to download `msc.sty` and put it in the Latex project directory. I included the package link. It runs with me exactly as I posted. The only difference I have the `msc.sty` file.

Comment: I don't think so, it is part of the texlive distribution. Or are you saying that you're using a style file that is different from the one in the texlive distribution, but carries the same name?

Comment: Sorry I do not get what you mean by texlive. I use MikTex. I have to download a file called msc.sty from the package link in the OP. Then, copy it in the same directory where the .tex file is. Otherwise, the script will not run.

Comment: Well, if I follow the link you provide, I read "contained in MikTeX as msc" and "contained in texlive as msc". It is definitely **not** recommended to load the style files into your project directory. Rather, you should use it as it is provided by your distribution. This will drastically increase your chances of getting some help in this forum.

Comment: @marmot can you plz see the edit.

Comment: Oh yes, that's very reminiscent of the errors I obtain. You may find it annoying to go through this here, but the packages get regularly updated and made compatible with each other. This is major effort for those providing them *for free*. So you may understand that it is your responsibility to use one consistent distribution rather than mixing style files from different installations. Now I strongly recommend that you fix the errors by including the `graphicx` package and reading the `msc` package distribution,

Comment: Thanks. The whole manual does not mention how to make multiple lines comment. The graphics is irrelevant as the diagram appears without it. The problem is when I want to to add multiple lines in the comment. Thanks any ways.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the development version of `msc.sty`, where the author has rewritten the entire thing to use TikZ instead of `pstricks`, you can modify the `every msccomment` style to include a `text width` setting. This makes the node a `minipage` like box of the defined width, and line breaking is automatic.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{msc} %for the diagrams
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!tp] 
\centering
\setmsckeyword{} %removes msc keyword from the title
\drawframe{no} %no frame

\begin{msc}[
  normal values,
  /msc/level height=0.6cm,
  /msc/label distance=0.5ex,
  /msc/first level height=0.6cm,
  /msc/last level height=0.6cm,
  /msc/top head dist=0,
  /msc/bottom foot dist=0
]{}

\setlength{\instwidth}{2\mscunit} 
\setlength{\instdist}{2\mscunit} %message width

\declinst{A}{}{A}
\declinst{B}{}{B}
\declinst{C}{}{C}

\mess {Message 1)}{A}{B}
\mess {Message1}{B}{C}
\nextlevel

\mess {Message2}{B}{C}
\nextlevel
\msccomment[%
  msccomment distance=1cm,
  side=right,
  /msc/every msccomment/.append style={
   text width=3cm
  }
  ]{Very long comment here I need multiple lines}{C}

\end{msc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```